# EF Core will not set value of nullable field to NULL

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I have an entity that has a nullable int which is a one-to-one foreign key to itself. Simplified, this is the entity:

```
public class Step
{
    public int StepId { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int? RelatedStepId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RelatedStepId")]
    public Step RelatedStep { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine - I'm able to set the `RelatedStepId` to the value of another record's `StepId`. However, there are times when I need to break this relationship. If I set `RelatedStepId` to `null` and then save changes, the field retains its previous value. I have verified that the `RelatedStepId` truly is `null`, but when I log the SQL being generated (using .EnableSensitiveDataLogging() so I can see the values) I can see that it is passing the previous value in the SQL, not `null`.

I feel like I must be missing something simple, but I've been searching and searching and so far I haven't found anything that relates to this specific issue. How do I get EF Core to actually send `null` as the value for `RelatedStepId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud set `RelatedStep` to null too. I guess you didn't clear this object.

Filling one of `RelatedStepId` or `RelatedStep` is enough for `EF` to save the value and if you don't want it, you have to clear both of them.

Comment: This was it. Bonehead move on my part - I didn't realize I needed to explicitly clear the navigation property as well. Thanks!